# How to set default value from JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i have checked this link [Set radio button 'checked' in jquery based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121785/set-radio-button-checked-in-jquery-based-on-id) However, seems not very suitable for me. This is my code

```
     <label for="basic" class="basic">Gender:</label>
    <fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-1" value="Male" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-mini-1">Male</label>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-3" value="Female"  />
    <label for="radio-mini-3">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
```

and

```
    <label for="select-choice-min" class="select">Living Place:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-min" id="livingPlace" data-mini="true">
    <optgroup label="AAA">
       <option value="123">123</option>
       <option value="456">456</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="BBB">
      <option value="789">789</option>
      <option value="246">246</option>
     </optgroup>


    </select>
```

can i simply use the following code to set default value? seems not work

```
        $("#livingPlace :selected").text(data[0].data.livingPlace);
        //$('#livingPlace option[value=data[0].data.livingPlace]').attr("selected",true);
        $("input[name=gender]:checked").val(data[0].data.gender);
```

Comment: Where is your json data?

Comment: $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?user_name='+localUsername+'&role='+localRole+'&jsoncallback=?', function(data)   i can sure that it works, as other text field can be also to  set default value

Comment: What i meant was that we need the json data/format which you are getting from server in response.

Comment: ([{"data":{"id":"8","livingPlace":"789","gender":"Female"}}]);  something like this=)

Answer (score 0):

You might want

```
$('input[name=gender][value="' + data[0].data.gender + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Sorry, missed `=` after `value`